# How to auto fill the a custom_field with post_title value in wordpress post edit?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I need in the act of publishing a post, a value insert in a custom_field,  the same post_title value!

```
function add_custom_field_automatically_two($post_ID) {
global $post;
$post_id = $post->ID;
global $wpdb;
//$my_customf = $post->post_title;
//$my_customf = get_the_title( $post_id );
$my_customf = "something string"; // worked, but I need post_title!       
add_post_meta($post_ID, 'my_customf', $my_customf, true);
}
add_action('publish_page', 'add_custom_field_automatically_two');
add_action('publish_post', 'add_custom_field_automatically_two');
?>


Thanks.
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, incomplete and way to broad. Please read the [how-to-ask-on-stackoverflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question with more information with attempts, related code and concrete question.

Comment: Sorry @Nrzonline I was in a rush and I thought I had not posted yet, I was just creating the topic and I had to leave and leave early, only now I could post. Mine is a simple case, see if you can help me please.